# GNOME sushi reopens video instead of closing it

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-sushi

I installed GNOME sushi on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it sometimes works just fine.

However, in most cases, when I preview a video by pressing <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>spacebar</kbd> again, it just doesn't close. Instead, the video preview is reopened.

Can someone give me a hint how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **double pressing space bar** when this happens, worked for me.

And this is a [**known bug**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-sushi/+bug/1876468), and will probably be fixed in future Nautilus update.

Comment: Oh my, I was using gnome-sushi for a year or more with this issue. Now, that I triyed double clicking it, it looks like it was fixed. Now it is working just fine. Thank you so much dude.